# Database lock Acquisition file when trying to install and configure HSQLDB

Tags: tomcat, hsqldb, juddi

I want to Create a directory under TOMCAT-HOME named db. so that i can create the HSQLDB database for the UDDI storage here.
Inorder to create a  UDDI database. I Opened a command prompt window and changed to the {TOMCAT-HOME}/common/lib directory. Then  I entered the following to start the HSQLDB admin GUI:
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager

In the GUI, I entered the following, leaving the rest as their default values:

Type:   HSQL Database Engine Standalone
URL:    jdbc:hsqldb:file:{TOMCAT-HOME}/db/uddi

But i got the error as database lock Acquisition file. What to do

Answer (score 0):

A `file:` database can be accessed by only one Java process and a lock mechanism prevents other processes from accessing the database. After executing the `SHUTDOWN` SQL statement in the DatabaseManager, the database will be closed and the Tomcat process can be started to access the database.